# What could happen if I install all server roles on Windows Azure Pack: Web Sites on one machine?

Tags: server, webserver, azure-web-app-service, azure-pack, web-admin

At work, I'm in the process of installing Windows Azure Pack: Web Sites in a VMWare ESXi lab environment. I have little available RAM and hard drive space on the ESXi.

I originally thought I would be able to do this without spending too much resources. The Azure Pack Express variant is advertised as if it only requires one machine with 8 GBs of RAM. However, after completing the first installation, I discovered that the Azure Pack: Web Sites extension requires no less than 7 different server roles *installed on 7 different machines*, each with Windows Server 2012 R2. I need a separate Cloud Controller, Cloud Management Server, Cloud Front End, Cloud Publisher, Cloud Shared Web Worker, Cloud Reserved Web Worker and Cloud File Server.

I have no way of freeing up that much resources. In the installation guide for [Windows Azure Pack](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469319.aspx#BKMK_CreateServers), they "advice" me to use separate VMs for each role, but they don't say explicitly that it won't work. **Is it because multiple server roles on one machine will strain resources, or is it because the roles are incompatible and will make the system malfunction?** In my case, the Azure Pack will only be used for penetration testing by a single user, so I imagine resources should not be a problem.

I'm not a web administrator, and I'm in over my head on this task. If anyone could give me some advice before I proceed on this, that would be much appreciated.

**TLDR:** Will there be a critical conflict if I install seven server roles on one machine, or will there just be a strain of resources?

Comment: `In my case, the Azure Pack will only be used for penetration testing by a single user, so I imagine resources should not be a problem.` what will that achieve when everything is on a same vm? rofl

Comment: It enables a pentester to poke at the virtualization container and test ways to abuse the application API. Or so I imagine.